# updating the angular version in a visual studio 2019 project

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2019

Im starting to learn angular and have hit a bump pretty quickly.  The angular project template in visual studio 2019 installs angular 8.  The latest version is 12, so I thought Id simply update to that version.  What a headache !  The most popular option seems to be to copy the src folder somewhere then delete the ClientApp folder in the angular src directory of the project and run this command line

ng new ClientApp

this creates the clientapp directory using the latest version of angular installed on my system.  This works and after checking the package.json file, the version has been updated.  I then copy the original app directory from my original project (so that I keep all the original pages, etc) back int the new src directory.  When I run the project again, it wont run, in the browser all I get is a message

'Cannot Get'

How on earth is it possible to simply update the angular version ?, there must be an easier way.  If I develop something with an older angular version and simply want to switch to a newer version, retaining my original code how can this be done ?  Surely in the real world this is a common practice, apps will be developed, then a new version of angular comes out and the app will need to be updated.  It seems incredibly complicated, I havent actually manged to get it to work.  Can anyone help ?

So I tried the update path as suggested but it didnt work, heres the error (I tried it wih version 9 too, same results, the version wasnt updated)

[image]

** update

managed to get to version 9 but with errors, so tried to go to 10, now I have this, what a painful experience, can anyone shed some light on this problem ?

[image]

Comment: Don't do copy paste of code to upgarde. Follow https://update.angular.io/ . It's very easy with just few  commands

Comment: Not sure how you come upon the "The most popular option seems to be to copy the src folder somewhere then delete..." part. Whether it was created by VS template or not, it's still a normal Angular app. Follow the normal update guide properly and you shouldn't have any issues. https://update.angular.io/

Comment: just updated my question with the error I got

Comment: wow, what an unbelievably painful experience that was, simply updating the version of a framework ! got there in the end